# is it possible to define an array directly within a JavaScript Object and then use the array.length property on a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The reason i am asking is because this code which has an array directly declared into the object will throw the following error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: projects is not defined

```
var client = {
    projects: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    test: function() {
        return projects.length;
    }
};
console.log(client.test());
```

Of course we can just declared the variable and then reference it within the object like this:

```
 var projects = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    var client = {
        projects: projects,
        test: function() {
            return projects.length;
        }
    };
    console.log(client.test());
```

And that would work. But i really want to know why in the world is the first example giving the error. What is wrong with it??

Comment: `return this.projects.length;`

Comment: Because that's not how JS objects work? Some basic JS O.O tutorials will clear this up for you quickly.

Comment: @DaveNewton Poor boy, give him some time to discover this. Then we could mark as duplicate his [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: @n00dl3 Fair enough—I’d already deleted my comment in preparation ;)

Comment: @daveNewton i know we can use this to refer to the object. What is not obvious to me, (maybe to you it is cause you are such a genius) is why we have to use the this keyword, when on the first example, it is evident that projects has been defined as a variable (just like on the second example). I thought the question was a bit more profound than it seemed.

Comment: Ok, maybe my mistake is that i was assuming that key value pairs were variables when they are not. Are they? heheh. Sorry for my existencial JavaScript questions.

Comment: @escolta13 Me being a genius isn’t related-what I’m saying is that there are thorough tutorials that discuss JS’s OOP nature that will answer this question, and your next one, better than an answer on SO. Key/value pairs are just that-JS objects aren’t classes (which JS doesn’t have despite ES6’s syntactic sugar).

Comment: All right, thanks @DaveNewton

Answer (score 4):

Use `this.projects.length`.

Within functions on the object, `this` refers to the current object.

Note that this will not work with arrow functions:

```
var client = {
    projects: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    test: function() {
        return this.projects.length;
    }
};
console.log(client.test());
```

`test: () => {` would not work. However, with new object literal declaration syntax you could write `test() {` and that would work.